# Finding a number between high and low

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to make a program that lets the user know if a number is in bounds between a low bound and a high bound, it also lets them know if its not an int or not. I've been trying to get it to run properly but for some reason the first time I input any value it returns its not an integer the second time I input a value it gives the proper value of if its higher or lower, I checked my indenting to see if that may cause it. I'm still not sure why. Any ideas on how to improve this code or make it function properly? Thank you!

The following is the main program:

```
import damn


HIGH = 10
LOW = 5
prompt = "Please enter a value Between 5 and 10"

numbers = damn.get_pos_integer(prompt, HIGH, LOW) 

print (numbers)
```

The following is my function:

```
def get_pos_integer(prompt, low, high):

    s = input(prompt)
    while True:
        if s.isdigit():
            x = int(s)
            if x < low:
                print("Number is too low")
            elif x > high:
                print("Number is too high")
            else:
                print("Number is an integer")
                return x
        else:
            print("Not a number")


x = get_pos_integer(prompt, 5, 10)
print("You entered", x)
```

Comment: What input is causing error, and what is the error on that input?

Comment: "... lets them know if its not an int or not". Well then, it is clearly not. ;)

Comment: I fixed it, it was me mixing up the function parameters. I also switched the s= input(... into the while loop. Thank you.

Comment: That's nice. Please, if my answer was to any help, then mark it at accepted :)

Answer (score 1):

In your function the syntax is

```
def get_pos_integer(prompt, LOW, HIGH):
```

while you call it with

```
number = get_pos_integer(prompt, HIGH, LOW)
```

You have switced `high` and `low`. You should probably check if your input `high > low`.

Answer (score 0):

input() return int or float.
Replace input() by raw_input(), it return a string to you.

Answer (score 0):

You wrote

```
s = input(prompt)
while True:
    # check that number
```

This means you ask for *one* number and repeatedly check it. If the number is invalid, this loop will continue forever.

You probably want

```
while True:
    s = input(prompt) # ask for new numbers until you get a valid one
    if s.isdigit():
        ...
```